# SQL count column on different conditions

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by

I have following trouble.

My SQL table looks following:

```
 | lead_id | user | status |
 | 1       | 2002 | ZP     |
 | 2       | 2003 | ZP     |
 | 3       | 2002 | NP     |
 | 4       | 2003 | NP     |
```

I would like to have my output like this:

```
 | user | countZP | countNP |
 | 2002 |    1    |    1    |
 | 2003 |    1    |    1    |
```

Is it possible to do that?

I tried something like this:

```
select user, count(a.status) as countZP, count(b.status) as countNP
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.lead_id = b.lead_id
where a.status = "ZP" or b.status = "NP"
group by user
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? `"ZP"` means column ZP in most cases, but maybe not here...?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM` and `CASE` rather than `COUNT`.

```
SELECT `user`,  
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'ZP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countZP,
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'NP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countNP
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `user`
```

With your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT `user`,  
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'ZP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countZP,
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'NP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countNP
FROM mytable
WHERE `status` IN ('ZP', 'NP')
GROUP BY `user`
```

Output

```
user  countZP  countNP
2002  1        1
2003  1        1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea161/3/0

Comment: wow thank you very much and what if i want to change user id to name when in other table i have user id | name ??

Comment: Something like a sub query with `name where user = sub.user`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    ( lead  int,  users  int,  status  varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ( lead ,  users ,  status )
VALUES
    (1, 2002, 'ZP'),
    (2, 2003, 'ZP'),
    (3, 2002, 'NP'),
    (4, 2003, 'NP')
;
Select users,MAX([ZP]) AS countZP,MAX([NP]) AS countNP from (
select lead ,  users ,  status ,count(status)S from @Table1
GROUP BY lead ,  users ,  status)T


PIVOT(MAX(S) FOR status IN ([ZP],[NP]))P
GROUP BY USERS
```

Comment: @martin let me know it meets your requirement